# Read specific columns from a csv file with csv module?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to parse through a csv file and extract the data from only specific columns.

Example csv:

```
ID | Name | Address | City | State | Zip | Phone | OPEID | IPEDS |
10 | C... | 130 W.. | Mo.. | AL... | 3.. | 334.. | 01023 | 10063 |
```

I'm trying to capture only specific columns, say `ID`, `Name`, `Zip` and `Phone`.

Code I've looked at has led me to believe I can call the specific column by its corresponding number, so ie: `Name` would correspond to `2` and iterating through each row using `row[2]` would produce all the items in column 2. Only it doesn't.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
import sys, argparse, csv
from settings import *

# command arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='csv to postgres',\
 fromfile_prefix_chars="@" )
parser.add_argument('file', help='csv file to import', action='store')
args = parser.parse_args()
csv_file = args.file

# open csv file
with open(csv_file, 'rb') as csvfile:

    # get number of columns
    for line in csvfile.readlines():
        array = line.split(',')
        first_item = array[0]

    num_columns = len(array)
    csvfile.seek(0)

    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
        included_cols = [1, 2, 6, 7]

    for row in reader:
            content = list(row[i] for i in included_cols)
            print content
```

and I'm expecting that this will print out only the specific columns I want for each row except it doesn't, I get the last column only.

Comment: why `'rb'` flag to `open()`? shouldn't it be simple `r`?

Comment: @Elazar: in Python 2 (which the OP is using) `"rb"` is appropriate for passing to `csv.reader`.

Comment: Why does your example CSV file show the pipe character as the delimiter but your example code use a space?

Comment: @KellyS.French I thought it would help visualize the data for the purposes of this question.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

The only way you would be getting the last column from this code is if you don't include your print statement **in** your `for` loop.

This is most likely the end of your code:

```
for row in reader:
    content = list(row[i] for i in included_cols)
print content
```

You want it to be this:

```
for row in reader:
        content = list(row[i] for i in included_cols)
        print content
```

Now that we have covered your mistake, I would like to take this time to introduce you to the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) module.

Pandas is spectacular for dealing with csv files, and the following code would be all you need to read a csv and save an entire column into a variable:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
saved_column = df.column_name #you can also use df['column_name']
```

so if you wanted to save all of the info in your column `Names` into a variable, this is all you need to do:

```
names = df.Names
```

It's a great module and I suggest you look into it. If for some reason your print statement was in `for` loop and it was still only printing out the last column, which shouldn't happen, but let me know if my assumption was wrong. Your posted code has a lot of indentation errors so it was hard to know what was supposed to be where. Hope this was helpful!

Comment: Is it possible to remove the index numbers from the query? @Ryan Saxe

Comment: Yes, just iterate through it in a for loop.

Comment: "Now that we have covered your mistake, I would like to take this time to introduce you to the pandas module."   Ah, yes you're not doing Python until you've used Pandas!

Answer (score 131):

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

columns = defaultdict(list) # each value in each column is appended to a list

with open('file.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f) # read rows into a dictionary format
    for row in reader: # read a row as {column1: value1, column2: value2,...}
        for (k,v) in row.items(): # go over each column name and value 
            columns[k].append(v) # append the value into the appropriate list
                                 # based on column name k

print(columns['name'])
print(columns['phone'])
print(columns['street'])
```

With a file like

```
name,phone,street
Bob,0893,32 Silly
James,000,400 McHilly
Smithers,4442,23 Looped St.
```

Will output

```
>>> 
['Bob', 'James', 'Smithers']
['0893', '000', '4442']
['32 Silly', '400 McHilly', '23 Looped St.']
```

Or alternatively if you want numerical indexing for the columns:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        for (i,v) in enumerate(row):
            columns[i].append(v)
print(columns[0])

>>> 
['Bob', 'James', 'Smithers']
```

To change the deliminator add `delimiter=" "` to the appropriate instantiation, i.e `reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=" ")`

Answer (score 36):

Use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd
my_csv = pd.read_csv(filename)
column = my_csv.column_name
# you can also use my_csv['column_name']
```

Discard unneeded columns at parse time:

```
my_filtered_csv = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=['col1', 'col3', 'col7'])
```

P.S. I'm just aggregating what other's have said in a simple manner. Actual answers are taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16503807/1091436) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41004218/1091436).

Comment: I think Pandas is a perfectly acceptable solution. I use Pandas often and really like the library, but this question specifically referenced the CSV module.

Comment: @frankV Well, the title, the tags and the first paragraph do not forbid pandas in any way, AFAI can see. I've actually just hoped to add a simpler answer to those already made here (other answers use pandas, too).

Answer (score 22):

You can use `numpy.loadtext(filename)`. For example if this is your database `.csv`:

```
ID | Name | Address | City | State | Zip | Phone | OPEID | IPEDS |
10 | Adam | 130 W.. | Mo.. | AL... | 3.. | 334.. | 01023 | 10063 |
10 | Carl | 130 W.. | Mo.. | AL... | 3.. | 334.. | 01023 | 10063 |
10 | Adolf | 130 W.. | Mo.. | AL... | 3.. | 334.. | 01023 | 10063 |
10 | Den | 130 W.. | Mo.. | AL... | 3.. | 334.. | 01023 | 10063 |
```

And you want the `Name` column:

```
import numpy as np 
b=np.loadtxt(r'filepath\name.csv',dtype=str,delimiter='|',skiprows=1,usecols=(1,))

>>> b
array([' Adam ', ' Carl ', ' Adolf ', ' Den '], 
      dtype='|S7')
```

More easily you  can use `genfromtext`:

```
b = np.genfromtxt(r'filepath\name.csv', delimiter='|', names=True,dtype=None)
>>> b['Name']
array([' Adam ', ' Carl ', ' Adolf ', ' Den '], 
      dtype='|S7')
```

Comment: @G Is there meant to be an r beside 'filepath\name.csv'?

Answer (score 19):

With [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) you can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with `usecols` parameter:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=['col1', 'col3', 'col7'])
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

s = '''
total_bill,tip,sex,smoker,day,time,size
16.99,1.01,Female,No,Sun,Dinner,2
10.34,1.66,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,3
21.01,3.5,Male,No,Sun,Dinner,3
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), usecols=['total_bill', 'day', 'size'])
print(df)

   total_bill  day  size
0       16.99  Sun     2
1       10.34  Sun     3
2       21.01  Sun     3
```

Answer (score 7):

Context: For this type of work you should use the amazing python petl library. That will save you a lot of work and potential frustration from doing things 'manually' with the standard csv module. AFAIK, the only people who still use the csv module are those who have not yet discovered better tools for working with tabular data (pandas, petl, etc.), which is fine, but if you plan to work with a lot of data in your career from various strange sources, learning something like petl is one of the best investments you can make. To get started should only take 30 minutes after you've done pip install petl. The documentation is excellent.

Answer: Let's say you have the first table in a csv file (you can also load directly from the database using petl). Then you would simply load it and do the following.

```
from petl import fromcsv, look, cut, tocsv 

#Load the table
table1 = fromcsv('table1.csv')
# Alter the colums
table2 = cut(table1, 'Song_Name','Artist_ID')
#have a quick look to make sure things are ok. Prints a nicely formatted table to your console
print look(table2)
# Save to new file
tocsv(table2, 'new.csv')
```

Answer (score 5):

I think there is an easier way

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('table1.csv')
ftCol = dataset.iloc[:, 0].values
```

So in here `iloc[:, 0]`, `:` means all values, `0` means the position of the column.
in the example below `ID` will be selected

```
ID | Name | Address | City | State | Zip | Phone | OPEID | IPEDS |
10 | C... | 130 W.. | Mo.. | AL... | 3.. | 334.. | 01023 | 10063 |
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd 
csv_file = pd.read_csv("file.csv") 
column_val_list = csv_file.column_name._ndarray_values
```

Comment: You'll have to `pip install pandas` first

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the way you can index and subset a pandas dataframe, a very easy way to extract a single column from a csv file into a variable is:

```
myVar = pd.read_csv('YourPath', sep = ",")['ColumnName']
```

---

A few things to consider:

The snippet above will produce a pandas `Series` and not `dataframe`.
The suggestion from ayhan with `usecols` will also be faster if speed is an issue.
Testing the two different approaches using `%timeit` on a 2122 KB sized csv file yields `22.8 ms` for the usecols approach and `53 ms` for my suggested approach.

And don't forget `import pandas as pd`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to process the columns separately, I like to destructure the columns with the `zip(*iterable)` pattern (effectively "unzip"). So for your example:

```
ids, names, zips, phones = zip(*(
  (row[1], row[2], row[6], row[7])
  for row in reader
))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('Train.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values
```

- `X` is a a bunch of columns, use it if you want to read more that one column
- `y` is single column, use it to read one column
- `[:, 1:-1]` are `[row_index : to_row_index, column_index : to_column_index]`

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_file:
    # the below statement will skip the first row
    next(csv_file)
    reader= csv.DictReader(csv_file)
   
    Time_col ={'Time' : []}
    #print(Time_col)
    for record in reader :
        Time_col['Time'].append(record['Time'])
        print(Time_col)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 1):

From [CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) you can import csv and use this code:

```
with open('names.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SAMPLE.CSV
a, 1, +
b, 2, -
c, 3, *
d, 4, /
column_names = ["Letter", "Number", "Symbol"]
df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv", names=column_names)
print(df)
OUTPUT
  Letter  Number Symbol
0      a       1      +
1      b       2      -
2      c       3      *
3      d       4      /

letters = df.Letter.to_list()
print(letters)
OUTPUT
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score -3):

To fetch **column name**, instead of using **readlines()** better use **readline()** to avoid loop & reading the complete file & storing it in the array.

```
with open(csv_file, 'rb') as csvfile:

    # get number of columns

    line = csvfile.readline()

    first_item = line.split(',')
```