# select and save desired columns using pandas - python

Tags: python, save, pandas

Let's say my file contains these data:

```
t   c   a
a   1   2
b   2   3
c   1   1
```

In order to select and save only the columns I'm interested in, I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503560/read-specific-columns-from-csv-file-with-python-csv?answertab=active#tab-top) and installed the pandas module. Then I did:

```
>>> df = pandas.read_csv('test')
>>> df
    t\tc\ta
 0  a\t1\t2
 1  b\t2\t3
 2  c\t1\t1
```

However, when I type `df.a` to select column "a" I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'a'
```

Also tried `df['t']` and got this error instead:

```
KeyError: u'no item named t'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify delimiter (default is `,`).

```
>>> import pandas
>>> with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
...     f.write('t\tc\ta\na\t1\t2\nb\t2\t3\nc\t1\t1\n')
... 

>>> df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv')
>>> df.columns
Index([t    c   a], dtype=object)

>>> df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv', delimiter='\t') # <--
>>> df.columns
Index([t, c, a], dtype=object)

>>> df['t']
0    a
1    b
2    c
Name: t
```