# Read specific columns in csv using python

Tags: python, sql, csv

I have a csv file that look like this:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| AAA | bbb | ccc | DDD | eee | FFF | GGG | hhh |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   1 |   2 |   3 |   4 |  50 |   3 |  20 |   4 |
|   2 |   1 |   3 |   5 |  24 |   2 |  23 |   5 |
|   4 |   1 |   3 |   6 |  34 |   1 |  22 |   5 |
|   2 |   1 |   3 |   5 |  24 |   2 |  23 |   5 |
|   2 |   1 |   3 |   5 |  24 |   2 |  23 |   5 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

...

How can I only read the columns "AAA,DDD,FFF,GGG" in python and skip the headers?
The output I want is a list of tuples that looks like this:
[(1,4,3,20),(2,5,2,23),(4,6,1,22)]. I'm thinking to write these data to a SQLdatabase later.

I referred to this post:[Read specific columns from a csv file with csv module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503560/read-specific-columns-from-csv-file-with-python-csv).
But I don't think it is helpful in my case. Since my .csv is pretty big with whole bunch of columns, I hope I can tell python the column names I want, so python can read the specific columns row by row for me.

Comment: If you can use other library, [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html) can help you easily.

Comment: I'm thinking using split(',') to get a list of headers and get the index of the column I want, then read the csv file... But I'm wondering if there are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def read_csv(file, columns, type_name="Row"):
  try:
    row_type = namedtuple(type_name, columns)
  except ValueError:
    row_type = tuple
  rows = iter(csv.reader(file))
  header = rows.next()
  mapping = [header.index(x) for x in columns]
  for row in rows:
    row = row_type(*[row[i] for i in mapping])
    yield row
```

Example:

```
>>> import csv
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> def read_csv(file, columns, type_name="Row"):
...   try:
...     row_type = namedtuple(type_name, columns)
...   except ValueError:
...     row_type = tuple
...   rows = iter(csv.reader(file))
...   header = rows.next()
...   mapping = [header.index(x) for x in columns]
...   for row in rows:
...     row = row_type(*[row[i] for i in mapping])
...     yield row
... 
>>> testdata = """\
... AAA,bbb,ccc,DDD,eee,FFF,GGG,hhh
... 1,2,3,4,50,3,20,4
... 2,1,3,5,24,2,23,5
... 4,1,3,6,34,1,22,5
... 2,1,3,5,24,2,23,5
... 2,1,3,5,24,2,23,5
... """
>>> testfile = StringIO(testdata)
>>> for row in read_csv(testfile, "AAA GGG DDD".split()):
...   print row
... 
Row(AAA='1', GGG='20', DDD='4')
Row(AAA='2', GGG='23', DDD='5')
Row(AAA='4', GGG='22', DDD='6')
Row(AAA='2', GGG='23', DDD='5')
Row(AAA='2', GGG='23', DDD='5')
```

Comment: I really like your solution. It's working efficiently. But what if I want to read the columns in different order, for say: "AAA, FFF, DDD, GGG"? Now the python is reading the selected columns in an alphabetic order.

Comment: It gives me an error `row = row_type(row[i] for i in mapping)
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 11 arguments (2 given)`

Comment: Ni Yan: It's late, I got cute, and slipped up in one of the interface differences between tuple and namedtuple.  I've edited the code and provided an example interactive session that uses it.

Answer (score 6):

I realize the answer has been accepted, but if you really want to read specific *named* columns from a csv file, you should use a `DictReader` (if you're not using `Pandas` that is).

```
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO

columns = 'AAA,DDD,FFF,GGG'.split(',')


testdata ='''\
AAA,bbb,ccc,DDD,eee,FFF,GGG,hhh
1,2,3,4,50,3,20,4
2,1,3,5,24,2,23,5
4,1,3,6,34,1,22,5
2,1,3,5,24,2,23,5
2,1,3,5,24,2,23,5
'''

reader = csv.DictReader(StringIO(testdata))

desired_cols = (tuple(row[col] for col in columns) for row in reader)
```

Output:

```
>>> list(desired_cols)
[('1', '4', '3', '20'),
 ('2', '5', '2', '23'),
 ('4', '6', '1', '22'),
 ('2', '5', '2', '23'),
 ('2', '5', '2', '23')]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import csv

DESIRED_COLUMNS = ('AAA','DDD','FFF','GGG')

f = open("myfile.csv")
reader = csv.reader(f)

headers = None
results = []
for row in reader:
    if not headers:
        headers = []
        for i, col in enumerate(row):
        if col in DESIRED_COLUMNS:
            # Store the index of the cols of interest
            headers.append(i)

    else:
        results.append(tuple([row[i] for i in headers]))

print results
```

Comment: Roger's `with` is better file handling. I'm still getting used to using that

Answer (score 1):

Context: For this type of work you should use the amazing python petl library. That will save you a lot of work and potential frustration from doing things 'manually' with the standard csv module. AFAIK, the only people who still use the csv module are those who have not yet discovered better tools for working with tabular data (pandas, petl, etc.), which is fine, but if you plan to work with a lot of data in your career from various strange sources, learning something like petl is one of the best investments you can make. To get started should only take 30 minutes after you've done pip install petl. The documentation is excellent.

Answer: Let's say you have the first table in a csv file (you can also load directly from the database using petl). Then you would simply load it and do the following.

```
from petl import fromcsv, look, cut, tocsv    

    #Load the table
    table1 = fromcsv('table1.csv')
    # Alter the colums
    table2 = cut(table1, 'Song_Name','Artist_ID')
    #have a quick look to make sure things are ok.  Prints a nicely formatted table to your console
    print look(table2)
    # Save to new file
    tocsv(table2, 'new.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your files and requirements are relatively simple and set, then once you know the desired columns, I would likely use split() to divide each data line into a list of column entries:

```
alist = aline.split('|')
```

I would then use the desired column indices to get the column entries from the list, process each with strip() to remove the whitespace, convert it to the desired format (it looks like your data has integer values), and create the tuples.

As I said, I am assuming that your requirements are relatively fixed. The more complicated or the more they are likely to change, the more likely that it will be worth your time to pick up and use a library made for manipulating this type of data.

Answer (score 0):

All other answers are good, but I think it would be better to not load all data at the same time because the csv file could be really huge. I suggest using a generator.

```
def read_csv(f, cols):
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) == 1:
            columns = row[0].split()
            yield (columns[c] for c in cols)
```

Which can be used for a for loop after

```
with open('path/to/test.csv', 'rb') as f:
    for bbb, ccc in read_csv(f, [1, 2]):
        print bbb, ccc
```

Of course you can enhance this function to receive the column's name instead of the index. To do so, just mix Brad M answer and mine.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help.

CSV

```
1997,Ford,E350,"ac, abs, moon",3000.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition""","",4900.00
1996,Jeep,Grand Cherokee,"MUST SELL! air, moon roof, loaded",4799.00
```

code

```
import csv   

def get_csv(file_name, names=None, usecols=None, mode='r', encoding="utf8",
            quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
            delimiter=',',
            as_obj=False):

    class RowObject:
        def __init__(self, **entries):
            self.__dict__.update(entries)

    with open(file_name, mode=mode, encoding=encoding) as csvfile:
        data_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quoting=quoting, delimiter=delimiter)
        for row in data_reader:
            if usecols and names:
                q = dict(zip(names, (row[i] for i in usecols)))
                yield q if not as_obj else RowObject(**q)
            elif usecols and not names:
                yield list(row[i] for i in usecols)
            elif names and not usecols:
                q = dict(zip(names, (row[k] for k, i in enumerate(row))))
                yield q if not as_obj else RowObject(**q)
            else:
                yield row
```

example

```
filename = "/csv_exe/csv.csv"
vs = get_csv(filename, names=('f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5'))
for item in vs:
    print(item)
```

result

```
{'f1': '1997', 'f4': 'ac, abs, moon', 'f3': 'E350', 'f2': 'Ford', 'f5': '3000.00'}
{'f1': '1999', 'f4': '', 'f3': 'Venture "Extended Edition"', 'f2': 'Chevy', 'f5': '4900.00'}
{'f1': '1996', 'f4': 'MUST SELL! air, moon roof, loaded', 'f3': 'Grand Cherokee', 'f2': 'Jeep', 'f5': '4799.00'}
```

example2

```
vs = get_csv(filename, names=('f1', 'f2'), usecols=(0, 4))
```

result2

```
{'f1': '1997', 'f2': '3000.00'}
{'f1': '1999', 'f2': '4900.00'}
{'f1': '1996', 'f2': '4799.00'}
```

example3

```
vs = get_csv(filename, names=('f1', 'f2'), usecols=(0, 2), as_obj=True)
```

result3

```
<__main__.get_csv.<locals>.RowObject object at 0x01408ED0>
<__main__.get_csv.<locals>.RowObject object at 0x01408E90>
<__main__.get_csv.<locals>.RowObject object at 0x01408F10>

for item in vs:
    print(item.f2)

E350
Venture "Extended Edition"
Grand Cheroke
```