# How to delete column from .csv file without reading the whole file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I generate very big .csv file but now it doesn't fit the RAM. So i decided to delete some inefficient columns to reduce the file size. How can I do that?

I tried data = `pd.read_csv("file.csv", index_col=0, usecols=["id", "wall"])` but it still doesn't fit the RAM.

File is about 1.5GB, RAM is 8GB.

Comment: do you need to read the whole csv for those columns? One thing that may help is to specify the dtype so it doesn't try to guess

Comment: @EdChum Yes, I need to read the index and "wall" columns. I know about "nrows" parameter but i need the ability to read the whole file.

Comment: possible dumb question are you running 64-bit python, OS and associated libraries?

Comment: A 1.5 GB file doesn't fit into 8 GB of RAM? Anyways, Apache Spark may be overkill, but worth a shot

Comment: Or stream the file though some command line operations rather than trying to store a whole dataframe in pandas

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting columns, you can also read specific columns from csv file using a `DictReader` (if you're not using `Pandas` ).

```
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO

columns = 'AAA,DDD,FFF,GGG'.split(',')


testdata ='''\
AAA,bbb,ccc,DDD,eee,FFF,GGG,hhh
1,2,3,4,50,3,20,4
2,1,3,5,24,2,23,5
4,1,3,6,34,1,22,5
2,1,3,5,24,2,23,5
2,1,3,5,24,2,23,5
'''

reader = csv.DictReader(StringIO(testdata))

desired_cols = (tuple(row[col] for col in columns) for row in reader)
```

Output:

```
>>> list(desired_cols)
[('1', '4', '3', '20'),
 ('2', '5', '2', '23'),
 ('4', '6', '1', '22'),
 ('2', '5', '2', '23'),
 ('2', '5', '2', '23')]
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20065131/6633975

**Using Pandas:**

Here is an example illustrating the answer given by EdChum. There is a lot of additional options to load a CSV file, check the [API reference](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

```
import pandas as pd


raw_data = {'first_name': ['Steve', 'Guido', 'John'],
        'last_name': ['Jobs', 'Van Rossum', "von Neumann"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
# Saving data without header
df.to_csv(path_or_buf='test.csv', header=False)
# Telling that there is no header and loading only the first name
df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='test.csv', header=None, usecols=[1], names=['first_name'])
df

  first_name
0      Steve
1      Guido
2       John
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is possible in pandas. You can try to do it in the Command Line. On Linux it will look like:

```
cut -f1,2,5- inputfile
```

if you want to delete columns with indexes 3 and 4.

Comment: cat: invalid option -- 'f'

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446255/how-to-remove-the-first-two-columns-in-a-file-using-shell-awk-sed-whatever