# Compare two files and return matching terms

Tags: python, csv

I'm having a little trouble with something I thought should be quite easy.

I have two files, both `tsv`. One is a list of names like so:

```
Thing1
Thing2
Thing3
Thing4
...
```

The other is a list of interactions between these 'things', it looks like so:

```
Thing1 Thing2 0.726
Thing3 Thing2 0.742
Thing1 Thing4 0.761
```

All I'd like to do is take the list and return the names of items on that list, which appear in my second interaction file. I thought this should be fairly straight forward but I can't seem to get it working.

So far I have tried a few things but the most basic looks like so:

```
import csv
import sys

ints = sys.argv[1]

name_list = open('Names', 'rb')
int_list = open(ints, 'rb')

for i in int_list:
    for names in name_list:
        if i == name:
            print(name)
```

I'm sure I'm missing something very basic here but any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers :)

Comment: Have you tried printing the variables inside the loop, to see what `row` is? (It is not `Thing1`...)

Comment: Also: You are importing the CSV lib at top. You might want to consider using it, as that will be much easier for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop for Parsing complex tab delimited/csv files in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108308/loop-for-parsing-complex-tab-delimited-csv-files-in-python)

Comment: You've imported the csv module, but you're not using to actually parse your CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

You must split your names into 3 parts (the first name of file, the interact file, and the value) like this:

```
for i in int_list:
    for names in name_list:
       name = names.split(' ')
```

after this split, you could use `name[0]` to test the correspondence.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas' dataframes might help you a lot with that.

```
import pandas as pd

name_list = pd.read_csv('Names',sep = '\t')
int_list = pd.read_csv('ints',sep = '\t')

int_list[int_list.isin(name_list)]
```