# Read a single column of a CSV and store in an array

Tags: python, csv, pandas

What is the best way to read from a csv, but only one specific column, like `title`?

```
ID | date|  title |
-------------------
  1|  2013|   abc |
  2|  2012|   cde |
```

The column should then be stored in an array like this:

```
data = ["abc", "cde"]
```

This is what I have so far, with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", index_col=2)
```

I've looked into [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503560/read-specific-columns-from-csv-file-with-python-csv). I still get an `IndexError: list index out of range`.

**EDIT**:

It's not a table, it's comma seperated like this:

```
ID,date,title
1,2013,abc
2,2012,cde
```

Comment: Is that really what your file looks like, with `|` and `--` and so on?  (Not really CSV, comma-separated-values, but we should be able to read it with some work.)

Comment: And are you certain that *all* rows have 3 columns? Sounds as if some of your rows are missing that third column, perhaps more.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One option is just to read in the entire csv, then select a column:

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

data['title']  # as a Series
data['title'].values  # as a numpy array
```

As @dawg suggests, you can use the usecols argument, if you also use the squeeze argument to avoid some hackery flattening the values array...

```
In [11]: titles = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=',', usecols=['title'], squeeze=True)

In [12]: titles  # Series
Out[12]: 
0    abc
1    cde
Name: title, dtype: object

In [13]: titles.values  # numpy array
Out[13]: array(['abc', 'cde'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> txt='''\
... ID,date,title
... 1,2013,abc
... 2,2012,cde'''
>>> data=pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), usecols=['title']).T.values.tolist()[0]
>>> data
['abc', 'cde']
```

Or, assuming that you have some blanks:

```
txt='''\
ID,date,title
1,2013,abc
2,2012,cde
3,2014, 
4,2015,fgh'''
table=pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), usecols=['title'])
print table
  title
0   abc
1   cde
2      
3   fgh
data=pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), usecols=['title']).T.values.tolist()[0]
print data
['abc', 'cde', ' ', 'fgh']
```

Or if you have variable number of data fields:

```
txt='''\
ID,date,title
1,2013,
2,2012,cde
3
4,2015,fgh'''

print pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), usecols=['title'])
  title
0   NaN
1   cde
2   NaN
3   fgh

print pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), usecols=['title']).T.values.tolist()[0]
[nan, 'cde', nan, 'fgh']
```

Comment: I think you assume I have sort of a table, but it is a comma-seperated csv, just presented in the wrong way (Excel-View).

Comment: You can use .ravel() or .flatten() on the data to get a flattened numpy array.

Answer (score 5):

Finally, it was much simpler:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv")
data.columns = ["ID", "date", "title"]
rawlist = list(data.title)
```

Comment: Like the output as a list, just what I was looking for.