# Reading specific Column Values from CSV and pass it to urllib as parameter in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, curl, urllib2

I am new to python and was trying to read a specific column from a CSV file.I am editing the problem now.

Here is the CSV file for eg:

```
one two three four
1    3    5    7
2    3    5    7
```

I wrote a very simple Python program as :(thanks to Amrit below for the modified mode).

```
import csv
with open('Activity_PSR.csv','rU') as csvFile:
    reader=csv.reader(csvFile,delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
         print row[6]
csvFile.close()
```

I am getting the specific column with Column header.I want the output of just the elements without the column header.

Once I get the output of this column ,I want to store it in a variable and use it in a CURL command to POST Data. CURL command equiv I beleive is urlib.

Here is the CURL POST Command:

```
curl -v -X POST -d ‘{“Organization_Id___ORACO__Account_Order":300100051155060,"}' slcaf961.us.oracle.com:10615/crmCommonApi/resources/11.1.10/__ORACO__Order_c
 -H "Content-Type:application/vnd.oracle.adf.resourceitem+json" --user “sales_representative”
```

And the urllib code I am planning to use:

```
import urllib2
data = '{“Organization_Id___ORACO__Account_Order":300100051155060"}'
url = 'slcad745.us.oracle.com:10618/crmCommonApi/resources/11.1.10/__ORACO__Order_c'
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
for x in f:
    print(x)
f.close()
```

In the data field here Instead of passing 300100051155060 directly I want to use the value I got from the CSV above and pass that as the Account-Id.

How to pass the value I got from the CSV and pass it to the JSON payload as a parameter ?
Need to store the value I got from CSV and store it in a Variable and pass it to the JSON payload/data as a parameter and execute the POST method.
Request folks to help me on how to acheive the above scenario

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503560/read-specific-columns-from-csv-file-with-python-csv will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code instead:

```
import csv
with open('test.csv','r') as csvFile:
    reader=csv.reader(csvFile,delimiter=',')
    reader.next()   # if you don't want to print columns headers
    for row in reader:
         print row[2]
csvFile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks Amritbir will try it out

Comment: Hi Amritbir how can I get the column values without the header.At the moment it prints the column with the Column header.how to ignore the Column header and print get the column values alone.

Answer (score 0):

This means that a row does not have a column on index 2. You need to create a guard:

```
for row in csv_f:
    # make sure row has value on column 2 - otherwise skip row
    if len(row) > 2:
        print row[2]
```

You can also use an exception, which in Python is considered cheap:

```
for row in csv_f:
    try:
        print row[2]
    except IndexError:
        print("skipping row %s" % str(row))
```

If you **know** all rows need to have a value there, make sure you're using the right delimiter using the `delimiter` argument to the reader's constructor.

Also, make sure you're closing the file **after** the loop:

```
for row in csv_f:
    # do stuff with 'row'
csv_f.close()
```

Comment: Hi Reut the problem its not selecting particular column values.In the CSV I have 4 columns and values in all 4 columns I am not sure why its still giving me list index out of range.

Comment: All I want to do is get say column 2 values as output and store it in a variable for further use.How to do that in this scenario.

Comment: Can you show the actual input? If you really have 4 values, this will not happen.

Comment: Sure I have Input CSV uploaded here I used

Comment: What if you tried specifying a delimiter and removing the dialect? `csv_f = csv.reader(open('test.csv','rU'), delimiter=',')`

Comment: Hi Reut thanks for the suggestion making tge change worked I have updated my question with the actual scenario I an looking for can you please check and suggest thanks for the help

Comment: This is a followup that completely changes the relevance of this answer as well as other. I suggest you accept an answer with respect to your original question and post a separate new question.

Comment: Sure Reut,I have accepted the answer and opened new topic with my q:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775208/reading-sepcific-csv-column-value-and-passing-it-to-curl-urllib-as-param-in-pyth

Answer (score 0):

You should consider working with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). It has a function called [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) that works *very* well. In your case the code to print out column three is

```
from pandas import *
csv_f=read_csv('test.csv', sep=r"\s*")
for a in csv_f['three']:
     print a
```

Of course, it has a bunch of functionalities that you should check out and see if you can make an use of.

Comment: Doesn't really help...some example code would be nice to add :)

Comment: @heinst yeah I was in the process of writing it when you commented! Please reconsider you -1? :)

Comment: Hi Tom if you can give me a example code on how to do my scenario using Pandas it would be very helpful.Thanks for the help

Comment: pandas is overkill for OP's request.  OP's inability to understand things like lengths of lists is just going to cause another bug someday whether using pandas or pure Python.  A more helpful answer would explain what OP is doing wrong.

Comment: @Jai I modified the answer to do what I think you want, which is to print column 'three'.

Comment: Thanks Tom will try it and let you know