# Python 2.7 reading csv fields rather than rows

Tags: python

Is it possible to read in a CSV file in Python one field at a time rather than an entire row?  I have an input that is a single row with a large amount of comma separated values.  I need to progress through the file one value at a time.

Comment: Couldn't you just read a row and then iterate through it, field by field?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read Specific Columns from csv file with Python csv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503560/read-specific-columns-from-csv-file-with-python-csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read the row and then use split

```
f=open(filename,'r')
fields=f.readline().split(',')
```

now fields[i] is the i-th field

Comment: This will not work on a "real" csv file that may have quoted fields.

Comment: This will work for my scenario.  My input will not be an actual csv file.  I was just using one to mimic the data I will receive from a piece of measurement equipment.

Answer (score 2):

You may get the csv data in the List and then iterate the list:

```
import csv
f1="filename.csv"
with open(f1, 'rU') as csvfile1:

    csvreader1 = csv.reader(csvfile1)
    for line1 in csvreader1:
        print "List of Values from File=", line1

    #Iterate List to get seperate items.
    for idx,item in enumerate(line1):
        print idx , ": ", item
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using a csv reader my_reader ...

```
row_stream = (row for row in my_reader)
field_stream = (field for field in row)
for field in field_stream:
    ....
```

This gives you a stream of fields instead of a sequence of csv rows.  If you replace the "for" expression with a generator comprehension, you can continue the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from user4421975 works well for me.  I also found that this works:

```
f=open(filename,'r')
reader = csv.reader(f)
row = reader.next()
```

Now row[i] has the different fields.