# How can I turn a csv file into a list of list in python

Tags: python, list, csv

I want to be able to turn csv file into a list of lists with the column values for each list. For example:

```
6,2,4
5,2,3
7,3,6
```

into

```
[[6,5,7],[2,2,3],[4,3,6]]
```

Ive only managed to open the file and only having success printing it as rows

```
with open(input,'rb') as csvfile:
        csv_file = csv.reader(csvfile)

        header = csv_file.next() 

        raw_data = csv_file
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503560/read-specific-columns-from-csv-file-with-python-csv

Comment: import csv

aList =[]
with open('/Users/YYY/Desktop/Workbook1.csv', 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        aList.append( row )
    print aList
# [['6', '2', '4'], ['5', '2', '3'], ['7', '3', '6']]

Comment: output needs to be arranged by columns so [[6,5,7],[2,2,3],[4,3,6]]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In case you sure it's fixed number of items in each row, you can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip):

```
import csv

with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    rows = csv.reader(csvfile)
    res = list(zip(*rows))
    print(res)
    # [('6', '5', '7'), ('2', '2', '3'), ('4', '3', '6')]
```

Or in case it's different number of items in row:

```
6,2,4
5,2
7
```

Use [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) and [filter](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#filter):

```
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest

with open('test.txt') as csvfile:
    rows = csv.reader(csvfile)

    res = list(zip_longest(*rows))
    print(res)
    # [('6', '5', '7'), ('2', '2', None), ('4', None, None)]

    res2 = [list(filter(None.__ne__, l)) for l in res]
    print(res2)
    # [['6', '5', '7'], ['2', '2'], ['4']]
```

Comment: or izip from itertools if you're using python2.x, and avoid turning it into a list unless you really NEED a list :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could probably start by reading it into a list of lists first:

```
from csv import reader as csvreader
with open(input, 'r') as fp:
    reader = csvreader(fp)
    li = list(reader)
```

Then chop it into a new sequence, I'm sure there are other tricks with itertools but this is what I came up with:

```
from itertools import count
def my_gen():
    for i in count():
        try:
            yield [x[i] for x in li]
        except IndexError:
            break
```

You can now turn the generator into a list, which will have the desired columns as rows.

```
list(my_gen())
```

Comment: @germn's answer is better than mine. zip/izip essentially does what my my_gen does.

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe like this...

```py
from csv import reader   

with open('test.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = reader(csv_file)
    rows = list(csv_reader)
    print(rows)
```