# Get the specific CSV column data based on column name

Tags: python-3.x

How i can get the specific column data from the csv file based on column name.
please suggest me to write the python script to get the same.

Comment: need to write the script without using pandas

Comment: Please show your work so far. Can you read in the file as a string? Have you tried splitting that string on commas and new lines? That would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

i basically suggest you look around the sites before asking questions like this since there are many answers there to satisfy your requirement have check out this link [Read specific columns from a csv file with csv module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503560/read-specific-columns-from-csv-file-with-python-csv)
i would suggest you to use pandas for this questions

```
    In [1]: dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8)

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-01  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059 -1.135632
2000-01-02  1.212112 -0.173215  0.119209 -1.044236
2000-01-03 -0.861849 -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804
2000-01-04  0.721555 -0.706771 -1.039575  0.271860
2000-01-05 -0.424972  0.567020  0.276232 -1.087401
2000-01-06 -0.673690  0.113648 -1.478427  0.524988
2000-01-07  0.404705  0.577046 -1.715002 -1.039268
2000-01-08 -0.370647 -1.157892 -1.344312  0.844885

In [4]: panel = pd.Panel({'one' : df, 'two' : df - df.mean()})

In [5]: panel
Out[5]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 8 (major_axis) x 4 (minor_axis)
Items axis: one to two
Major_axis axis: 2000-01-01 00:00:00 to 2000-01-08 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: A to D
```

and you could get the column using

```
In [15]: df.A
Out[15]: 
2000-01-01   -0.282863
2000-01-02   -0.173215
2000-01-03   -2.104569
2000-01-04   -0.706771
2000-01-05    0.567020
2000-01-06    0.113648
2000-01-07    0.577046
2000-01-08   -1.157892
Freq: D, Name: A, dtype: float64
```

i took this example from pandas home page give credits to them for building such a fascinating library.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.i have done this thing by using pandas already. but i don't wanna use panda for the given question. if you will guide me to solve the given question without pandas, it will be good for me