# Transpose data in columns to one row in CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am using Python 2.7 on Windows7.
I just learned Python for 2 days and got some CSV modules unfamiliar, hope to obtain your help here.

My current output(CSV data) is like this:

```
Angle Dist Intensity Error
0      0    32896   8080
1      0    32896   8080
2      0    32896   8080
3      0    32896   8080
4      0    32896   8080
5      0    32896   8080
6      0    32896   8080
7      0    32896   8080
```

My question is, how to transpose/rearrange data from columns to one row in Python? To be more specific, I would like to get the following format:

```
Angle 1 2 3 4...7 Dist 0 0 0...0 Intensity # # # # ... Error # # # # ...
```

My current code is:

```
with open("C:\Logging\\" + date + "Result.csv", 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        csv.writer(f, row)
```

Comment: There are many questions on SO that deal around the same issue. One such question can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503560/read-specific-columns-from-a-csv-file-with-csv-module. In your case, you would be selecting all columns instead of specific columns. Hope it helps

Comment: What are your delimiters, because they are clearly not commas. tabs or spaces?

Comment: hi @PaulRooney the delimiters are commas. The output is like: A,B,C,D (first row)  x1,y1,m1,n1 (second row) x2,y2,m2,n2 (third row)

Comment: Thanks @PedroLobito I tried out the link, but got an error on 'print(y+'\t', end='')' as 'invalid snytax'. Besides, his code is just 'print' to python but my case is print to CSV file in one row. So I think i need to search around more~~~

Comment: @Amber.G: The answer to the duplicate question is written in Python 3, For Python 2 use `print y+'\t',` —note the trailing comma.

Comment: @Amber.G: If you want all the data to become one row of a csv file, instead of printing it you will need to concatenate the results of all the items returned from the `zip()` call and write that to a new csv file. You can do the latter by creating a `csv.writer` instance from a new file opened for writing (`mode='wb'`).

Answer (score 1):

If pandas is not too much of an overkill for you, the following snippet should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename)
df.values.flatten()
```

Comment: it looks like i have trouble installing Pandas: I followed installation step by step until the last step 'pip install pandas' and got 'requirement already satisfied' (I went through the steps twice to double-confirm...). But when use Panda in my python, I got an error 'No module named pandas'...