# exporting one column to django database with python

Tags: python, django, database, excel

I have an excel file, in which there are emails of users in column F. I would like to get the emails in each row and import into a django database. However; as I am very new to Django, I do not understand how to do it. Here is what I tried:

```
import openpyxl
from ms.common.models import User, Participant, Question, Answer


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('list.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_names()
for row in ws.iter_rows('F{}:F{}'.format(ws.min_row,ws.max_row)):
    for cell in row:
        print cell.value

 #create email
    participant, created = Participant.objects.get_or_create(mail=user.username)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read specific columns from a csv file with csv module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503560/read-specific-columns-from-a-csv-file-with-csv-module)

Comment: Ok i changed the first line and now i can get all the email addresses, how can I add these to the participant model?
 participant, created = Participant.objects.get_or_create(mail=user.username) is this okey°

Comment: what about `participant = Participant.objects.create(mail=cell.value)` ?