# Automated edit of an excel file

Tags: excel, csv, ftp, automation

I've got no experience in how to automate tasks in excel but here is my scenario. I have a CSV file which is uploaded to an FTP server every 4 hours from my distributor, in this feed there are around 50 different categories of products, i need to find a way to automatically remove categories i do not need and then for it to save the revised in FTP.

I am trying to import my suppliers products into my ecommerce store and do not want half of the categories that include in their feed. I've asked them directly about selecting certain categories but they said that's not possible.

Can what i ask be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [Python](https://www.python.org/)'s ability to [read and write .csv files](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Check out these two links also:

- https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-read-and-write-csv-files-in-python--cms-29907
- [Read specific columns from a csv file with csv module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503560/read-specific-columns-from-a-csv-file-with-csv-module)

I think after informing yourself on *how to automate tasks in excel*, then you can ask better questions about the issues in your attempt to tackle the problem.