# Python3,dictionary from csv file to count frequency of words

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, word-frequency

I am trying to write a function that reads a CSV file of students volunteers with different degrees. The aim of the function is to create a dictionary where keys are the degrees and the values are the frequency of the degrees.

**Data is organized as follows;**

```
name    degree     email

ABC     PhD.       abd@gmail.com
CDE     Ph.D.      cde@gmail.com
FGH     MD,PHD     fgh@gmail.com
```

**Aim to get a dictionary as follows:**

```
#degree_count{'phd':3,'md':1}

def degree_frequency(csv_file):
    f = open('csv_file')
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)
    #Creating a list to store all the degrees from the csv file
    student_degree_list=[]
    #Creating an empty dictionary to count the frequency
    degree_count={}
    for row in csv_f:
        student_degree_list.append(row[1]) 
    #Replacing fullstops to account for variations in writing degrees ( eg JD vs J.D)
    [word.replace(".", "") for word in student_degree_list]
    [word.lower() for word in student_degree_list]
    for ele in student_degree_list:
        if ele in degree_count:
            degree_count[ele]=degree_count[ele]+1
        else:
            degree_count[ele]=0
    return degree_count
```

Comment: So what's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: @learning_python can you use panda ?

Comment: @Aran Frey: I am trying it on an interactive platform.It just says that test cases failed.Not pinpointing the problem.So I am not sure whats wrong with the code.

Comment: @Tanmay Jain: I have been specifically told not to use pandas.

Comment: @learning_python oh ohk will edit the answer

Comment: @learning_python what about Counters [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: @Tanmay Jain.Can use counters. Thanks for the solution with pandas.Pandas is easier to understand for me

Comment: @learning_python see my updated code

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem was that the below code has no effect unless you assign it to a variable.

```
[word.replace(".", "") for word in student_degree_list]
[word.lower() for word in student_degree_list]
```

Also, if a degree has 1 occurrence shouldn't it be set to 1 and not 0?

Working code:

```
#degree_count{'phd':3,'md':1}

def degree_frequency():
    f = open('csv_file')
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)
    # Creating a list to store all the degrees from the csv file
    student_degree_list = []
    # Creating an empty dictionary to count the frequency
    degree_count = {}
    for row in csv_f:
        student_degree_list.append(row[1])
    #Replacing fullstops to account for variations in writing degrees ( eg JD vs J.D)
    student_degree_list = [word.replace('.','').lower() for word in student_degree_list]
    for ele in student_degree_list:
        if ele in degree_count:
            degree_count[ele] += 1
        else:
            # Supposed to be 1?
            degree_count[ele]=0
    return degree_count
```

Comment: Okay then, why not just use one list comprehension?, `[word.replace(".", "").lower() for word in student_degree_list]`

Comment: I'm confused. I reused his list comprehension but assigned the resulting new list to the student_degree_list variable so that it actually changed the list.

Comment: What do you mean, i basically merged the two list comprehensions

Comment: Okay, I see what you are saying. I did only use one list comprehension. Look at my answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv 
from collections import Counter

columns = defaultdict(list) # each value in each column is appended to a list

with open('csv_file.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f) # read rows into a dictionary format
    for row in reader: # read a row as {column1: value1, column2: value2,...}
        for (k,v) in row.items(): # go over each column name and value 
            columns[k].append(v) # append the value into the appropriate list
                                 # based on column name k
```

credit for [csv reader code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16503661/6360875)

```
degree_list = columns['degree']
degree_list_clean = []

for cad_degrees in degree_list:
    cad_degrees_lst = cad_degrees.split()
    for degree in cad_degrees_lst:
        degree_clean = degree.strip().replace('.','').lower()
        degree_list_clean.append(degree_clean)
```

#### option 1

```
output_dict_counter_version = dict(Counter(degree_list_clean))
print(output_dict_counter_version)
```

#### option 2

```
degree_frequency_dict = {}

for deg in degree_list_clean:
    if deg in degree_frequency_dict:
        degree_frequency_dict[deg] += 1
    else:
        degree_frequency_dict[deg] = 1

print(degree_frequency_dict)
```

#### Using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

data = pd.read_csv("csv_file.csv")
degree_list = data['degree'].tolist()


degree_list_clean = []

for cad_degrees in degree_list:
    cad_degrees_lst = cad_degrees.split()
    for degree in cad_degrees_lst:
        degree_clean = degree.strip().replace('.','').lower()
        degree_list_clean.append(degree_clean)

print(dict(Counter(degree_list_clean)))



'''
------------------ Input
name,degree,email
ABC,PhD. ,abd@gmail.com
CDE,Ph.D. ,cde@gmail.com
FGH, MD PHD ,fgh@gmail.com

-------------------- Output
{'phd': 3, 'md': 1}
'''
```