# Reading text file using pandas using python

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to Python. I am trying to read my text file using python Data Science library Pandas. But I get an error of Unicode which I don't understand.If you could help me then it would be very beneficial to me. I am uploading my code here:

```
import pandas as pd
text = pd.read_csv("/home/system/Documents/Heena/NLP/modi.txt", sep = " ", header = None)
```

**Error Code:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/system/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/home/system/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 446, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "/home/system/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1036, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/home/system/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1848, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 876, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 891, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 945, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 932, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2112, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 62 fields in line 7, saw 67
```

Comment: Can you give some example datas in your modi.txt?

Comment: I guess, you have a problem with the data. Therefore carefully review the TXT file

Comment: i think its because of uneven number of spaces in the text..thats why its not getting converted to df

Comment: Data has unwanted space. The data as follows:       My dear countrymen, I convey my best wishes to all of you on this auspicious occasion of Independence Day. Today, the country is brimming with self-confidence. The country is scaling new heights by working extremely hard, with a resolve to realize its dreams. Todays dawn has brought a new spirit, a new enthusiasm, a new zeal and a new energy with it.

My dear countrymen, in our country, there is a Neelakurinji flower which blooms once every 12 years.

Comment: What would be the solution? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Because the data inside a space character, CVS perceives this as a different column. As a solution to this, separate the data with a different character. Then make the sep value this character. Example;

### test.csv

```
data1;data2;data3
My dear countrymen;12;test data1
I convey my best wishes to all of you on this auspicious occasion of Independence Day.;45;test data2
```

### test.py

```
import pandas as pd
text = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep = ";")
```

You can also look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21045966/9789543)

Comment: My file is text file and it has large amount of data. I have also tried with read_fwf() function to read text file. Using this function I am able to read file but when I apply Natural Language Processing functions that time error occurs. i.e.  for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object