# Python: How to quickly create a pandas data frame with only specific columns from a big excel sheet?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, large-data

I have an excel file with only one sheet. The size of the excel file is ~900 Mb and contains thousands of rows and hundreds of columns

I want to extract only a few columns (say `Name`, `Numbers` & `Address`) from the excel sheet and do data manipulations.

Since the excel file is huge, the traditional method of creating the data-frame using pandas and then extraction of columns takes a lot of time.

```
ExcelFile = pd.read_excel(fileAddress, sheet_name="Sheet1")
```

Is there a faster way to extract the columns from the excel file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps

There are a few ways you try and take the best approach that fits for you.

**1. Specify the required columns while loading the data.** (just like `Andy L.` answer)

```py
df = pd.read_excel(fileAddress, header=0, sheet_name='Sheet1', 
                                usecols=['Name', 'Numbers', 'Address'])
```

**2. Specify dtypes**

Pandas, for every data read operation, does a heavy lifting job of identifying the data type by itself. This consumes both memory and time. Also, this needs the whole data to be read at a time.

To avoid it - Specify you column data types(`dtype`)

Example:

```
pd.read_csv('sample.csv', dtype={"user_id": int, "username": object})
```

Available data types in pandas

```py
[numpy.generic,
 [[numpy.number,
   [[numpy.integer,
     [[numpy.signedinteger,
       [numpy.int8,
        numpy.int16,
        numpy.int32,
        numpy.int64,
        numpy.int64,
        numpy.timedelta64]],
      [numpy.unsignedinteger,
       [numpy.uint8,
        numpy.uint16,
        numpy.uint32,
        numpy.uint64,
        numpy.uint64]]]],
    [numpy.inexact,
     [[numpy.floating,
       [numpy.float16, numpy.float32, numpy.float64, numpy.float128]],
      [numpy.complexfloating,
       [numpy.complex64, numpy.complex128, numpy.complex256]]]]]],
  [numpy.flexible,
   [[numpy.character, [numpy.bytes_, numpy.str_]],
    [numpy.void, [numpy.record]]]],
  numpy.bool_,
  numpy.datetime64,
  numpy.object_]]
```

(as you can see the list is too long, so if you specify the dtypes it would speed up your job)

**3. You use a converter in case you need help in data conversions in your data.**

(Almost like 2, an alternative of 2).

In cases like null values or empty, you can easily deal here. (Disclaimer: I never tried this)

Example

```py
def conv(val):
    if not val:
        return 0    
    try:
        return np.float64(val)
    except:        
        return np.float64(0)

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', converters={'COL_A':conv,'COL_B':conv})
```

**4. Reading the data in chunks always helps.**

```py
chunksize = 10 ** 6
for chunk in pd.read_csv('sample.csv', chunksize=chunksize):
    process(chunk)
```

One thing to note is to treat each `chunk` like a separate data frame. Helps read larger files like 4 GB or 6 GB also.

**5. Use pandas low_memery option.**

Use (`low_memory=False`) to explicitly tell pandas to load larger files into memory or in case you are getting any memory warning.

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', low_memory=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may pass `usecols` to `read_excel` to import only specific columns from excel to `df`. If you use pandas 0.24+, `read_excel` is able to read directly on columns values, so just pass `usecols` with list of columns values

```
df = pd.read_excel(fileAddress, header=0, sheet_name='Sheet1', 
                                usecols=['Name', 'Numbers', 'Address'])
```

---

On pandas < 0.24, `usecols` doesn't understand excel cell values. You need to know  `Excel column letters` corresponding to `Name`, `Numbers`, `Address` or their integer locations.

For example: `Name` is at `B`; `Numbers` at `G`; `Address` at `AA`

```
df = pd.read_excel(fileAddress, header=0, sheet_name='Sheet1', usecols='B,G,AA')
```

If you know their integer locations, you may use them in place of 'B', 'G', 'AA' such as `usecols=[1, 6, 26]`

Answer (score 0):

you can copy the columns of your interest from the file.xlsx to another.xlsx and then make the reading with pandas from another.xlsx

Comment: It won't be feasible on large scale for multiple Excel files

Answer (score 0):

You can look up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41004218/1256837), because pandas provide such specific methods.

But more natively it will work like that:

```py
import csv
import toolz.curried as tc
import pandas as pd

def stream_csv(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        yield from csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')  # you can use any delimiter

file_path = '../../data.csv'
relevant_data = map(tc.keyfilter(lambda column_name: column_name in ['a', 'b']),
                                stream_csv(file_path))

pd.DataFrame(relevant_data)
```

Note that everything but pandas ist a generator function and thus is memory efficient.