# How to print a specific a column in a csv file in python?

Tags: python, csv

This is how i made my CSV file:

```
with open('Mail_Txt.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames= ['Sender', 'Subject', 'Snippet']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames , delimiter=',')
    for val in final_list:
        writer.writerow(val)
```

I try many methods to print the Sender column of the CSV file. But I fail all the time. so, help me to print the first or `'Sender'` column of the CSV file

Comment: You want to print the first column values when writing into the file?

Comment: Please give a sample of your data and the desired result!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503560/read-specific-columns-from-a-csv-file-with-csv-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading from a csv file is symetric from writing. The main difference is that as you have skipped the header line, you will use a simple reader and get sequences instead of mappings:

```
with open('Mail_Txt.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader= csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for val in reader:
        print(val[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use use the DictReader function to accomplish this.

```
with open('yourFile') as f:
    data = [row["Sender"] for row in DictReader(f)]
    print(data)
```