# What code should I use in extracting specific column (with specific data) from a csv file to python. It can be either pandas or numpy

Tags: python

please see attached photo
[here's the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kusL5.png)

I only need to import a specific column with conditions(such as specific data found in that column). And also, I only need to remove unnecessary columns. dropping them takes too much code. What specific code or syntax is applicable?

Comment: Kindly give us an example of desired result. And also share the necessary code in code block not image.

Answer (score 0):

How to get a column from pandas dataframe is answered in  [Read specific columns from a csv file with csv module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503560/read-specific-columns-from-a-csv-file-with-csv-module)

To quote:

> Pandas is spectacular for dealing with csv files, and the following
> code would be all you need to read a csv and save an entire column
> into a variable:
>
> ```
> import pandas as pd
> df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
> saved_column = df.column_name #you can also use df['column_name']
> ```

So in your case, you just save the the filtered data frame in a new variable.
This means you do `newdf = data.loc[......` and then use the code snippet from above to extract the column you desire, for example `newdf.continent`

Comment: somehow, im getting errors in 'saved_column'. can i save multiple columns? I used this code, but it happened to have error. what's wrong? when i use only one column and snippet, it works. here's what i have done
saved_column = df['location', 'location' ,'date', 'total_cases', 'new_cases', 'total_deaths', 'new_deaths']